# Force on a charged particle in a field of an EM wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

For example if there is a charge q with mass m travelling with a velocity v "in the field" of a plane electromagnetic wave that is travelling in the z direction (in free space). My question is what would the force and direction (if any) be if the particle was travelling in the same direction as the wave?

Comment: Calculate the field at the position of the charge and you got the force.

Comment: What is the direction of the magnetic and electric fields if the particle was moving in the same direction as the EM wave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a positive charge, the particle moves in the direction of the electric field and vice versa for a negative charge.

However, there also exists another force called the Lorentz force. It essentially states that, if a particle is moving with a velocity perpendicular to a magnetic field, a force is produced in a direction mutually perpendicular to the velocity and magnetic field.

To sum up the forces acting on a moving particle by an electric and magnetic field:

$$ {\vec F} = q({\vec E} + {\vec v}\times{\vec B}) $$

Use this image to deduce the motion of a proton and electron that is travelling in the same direction as the propagation of an electromagnetic wave:

[image]

Comment: Does this then mean that it would essentially move in a helical trajectory around the axis of the direction the wave is travelling?

Comment: Assume the electromagnetic wave and proton are propagating toward the right (positive x-axis). The force on the proton is therefore in the direction of the positive y-axis. What about the Lorentz force's direction?

Comment: Well the proton would move with sinusoidal motion because of the Electric field would it not? But combining it with the magnetic field would it not also curve around the axis?

Comment: You're right about the electric field. However, check the Lorentz force, which is **mutually perpendicular** to the velocity and magnetic field. Use the right-hand rule for cross products in $ {\vec v}\times{\vec B}$.

Comment: Oh wait think i understand,  v x B will create a force on the proton in the opposite way to the electric field?  So overall it will be sinusoidal motion in the y direction. But in the case that the electric and magnetic fields equal each other the proton will continue on its path unaffected?

Comment: Correct! The proton will move in the same direction unhindered (which is what I inferred from your last statement; the sinusoidal motion does not appear). Try to work it out for the electron?

Comment: Thank you! I'm just wondering if the proton in this situation is totally unaffected. In the question it just says velocity v so if one of the forces happens to be larger/smaller than the other would it not move with sinusoidal motion in the y axis? The force would only vanish in the particular case where the forces from both fields perfectly cancel out.

Comment: You're sort-of right. For the net force to be zero, the force from the electric field should equal the Lorentz force in magnitude and face the opposite direction $ {\vec E}  = -{\vec v}\times{\vec B} $.